# Pasar datos de un js externo en vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

he estado intentando importar un js externo local a un componente de vue, y poder usar los datos de ese archivo en un componente pero no he podido con la importación,
actualmente lo tengo así:

ejemplo1.js

```
var script = {
    asd='aja';
}

export script;
```

en el componente puse la siguiente línea

componente.vue

```
 import script as mykey from '../scripts/ejemplo1.js';
```

el error que me sale es un error de sintaxis en la linea de importación del componente de vue

Unexpected token, expected "," (2:10)

pero no veo el error, de antemano gracias al que me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es que estás intentando exportar un objeto y la sintaxis para construir ese objeto la tienes mal

Esto

```
var script = {
    asd='aja';
}

export script;
```

Debería ser esto

```
var script = {
    asd: 'aja'
}

export script;
```

Si en el objeto llegas a tener múltiples elementos los puedes separar con una coma, así

```
var script = {
    asd: 'aja'
}

export script;
```

---

Te puedes ahorrar el paso de utilizar el `as` si utilizas un export default así:

```
var script = {
    asd: 'aja',
    elemento2: 'hi'
}

export default script;
```

**Lo importas así:**

```
import mykey from '../scripts/ejemplo1.js';
```

Comment: Es verdad claramente el error fue humano jajajaaja, muchas gracias amigo